# Facebook API post not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

With certain facebook posts, that are seemingly completely public (for [example](https://www.facebook.com/chiara.beebe/videos/10153801897821136/)) I am unable to pull their information from the graph API no matter what combination of permissions / application / access_token I give it.

Even worse, I just get a generic error:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=10153801897821136&version=v2.5

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "GU3r05xB4VK"
  }
}
```

It seems that for whatever reason facebook has decided that I shouldn't be able to view this post (likely because of privacy settings) but I can very obviously view the actual post on facebook, even as a logged out user.

Any thoughts as to how to get this to work via the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within Facebook API, a public post that can be retrieved, refers to a post published by a Facebook page not a Facebook user profile.

In order to view this post, you will need `user_posts` and `user_friends` for the owner of that video and the querying user.

So for querying userA to get a public video from userB (who is a friend of userA), the permissions for both are

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "permission": "user_friends",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "user_posts",
      "status": "granted"
    },
    {
      "permission": "public_profile",
      "status": "granted"
    }
  ]
}
```